# Find the intersection point of a logarithmic and a quadratic functions.

Tags: logarithms, quadratics, absolute-value

**Situation**

I have following equation:

$|\log_{10}x| + (x-1)^2 = a$ or I think it will be better to write it in following form: $|\log_{10}x| = - (x-1)^2 + a$. I think with this, we can draw the parabola way better.

**The question**

Find out the the **x** when `a = 82` and $x \in Z.$

**What I've tried**

- Well... I thought maybe we can solve like a usual $|f(x)|=g(x)$ and find out what happens:

$|\log_{10}x|=-(x-1)^2+82$

$
  \begin{cases} 
  -(x-1)^2+82 \geqslant 0 \\
  \log_{10}x = -(x-1)^2+82 \quad OR \quad \log_{10}x=(x-1)^2-82   
  \end{cases}
 $

After simplifying, I found out that I can't do really much here.

- Second option was to draw the graph. After doing it manually by hand(which wasn't that hard) I tried plot it with a program (called Desmos) to see if I was missing something.

[image: List item]

What I have found out is that

1. when my **a** is `0`, then I have only one `x`.
2. when my **a** is greater than `0`, then I have 2 `x`s.
3. when my **a** is less than `0`, then I have no solution.

But I wasn't able to find the intersection point.

How do you solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Do you know Newton's method?

Comment: Yes, I do. But is it really the elegant way of solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately, for these cases, it is. No one has so far found out an elegant way of solving such eqns, especially when the two sides have expressins that belong to different classes, such as exponential, polynomial, logarithmic and so on. Or sometmes, you might get lucky by trial-and-error method. Such as for the eqn x+cos(x)=pi/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS is an integer, so the LHS must also be an integer, i.e. $x$ is a power of ten. Eyeballing shows that $x=10$ works.

Comment: Can you please clarify why it should have been a power of 10?

Comment: @Hrant Did you notice the $x\in\mathbb Z$ part of the question? Otherwise the problem wouldn't have been given to you.

Comment: Also I think the other `x` is not an `int`.

Comment: Maybe you're right I just thought there is something we could do about this problem.